# Could not load file or assembly Magick.Net on Elastic Beanstalk Deployment

Tags: c#, .net, dll, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, magicknet

I am getting the following error when deploying my project to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-x86.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

I have many other DLLs in the bin folder, and this one the only one that throws this error. The DLL doesn't have any dependencies as far as I know.

I don't get this error when running locally and the dll is set to "Do not copy" in the advanced options, like the other DLLs.

I am running ASP.NET 4.5 / C# Project

Running dependency walker on the EC2 server of the Elastic Beanstalk I get:

[image]

How can I make this dll load when launching my project on Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: So magik.net dll is into the GAC, not in the bin folder?

Comment: It is in the bin folder (Magick.NET-x86.dll). How an I make it available in the GAC? - I did put a reference to it thought. If its something need to be done on the server it's not good, because I need it to be done in visual studio because more servers will be deployed automatically using Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: you probably just miss the C++ runtimes redist.

Comment: @FelicePollano installing the runtime manually is not an option because I am using elastic beanstalk. I need some way to make it work when deploying the project from within visual studio using the ASW for Visual Studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`The specified module could not be found.`

This normally implies that the module specified (Magick.NET-x86.DLL) isn't the issue, but rather a dependency of Magick.NET-x86.DLL cannot be found. Specifically, a non CLR based dependency.

The best way to determine native dependencies is with a dependency viewer. You can find one here: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Open the Magick.NET-x86.DLL in the depends.exe program and look at the dependencies. If you can't do this on the amazon instance, you'll have to do it on your PC. Make sure that all dependencies are located, and exist within the same folder as the application .EXE

I did this with the following file downloaded from their website: Magick.NET-6.8.8.701-Q16-x64-net40-client

Based on the depencies I see when I do this, the most likely culprit is not having the C++ 2012 runtime. Note that this runtime is for the latest 64bit DLL i downloaded from their website. If you are using an older version it may be a different runtime.

To find out the correct runtime, google the c++ DLL name. E.g. MSVCP110.dll == 2012

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: Hi Jon, I've added an image of the output from the EC2 in the body of the question, can you please take a look.

Comment: Yup, as I said, this is the c++ 2012 runtime missing. Get that installed on the PC and you should be good.

Comment: Do you mean on my PC. Will it work on the Elastic Beanstalk once I auto deployed it from visual studio?

Comment: Where ever the code that uses magick is running, is where you need to install the C++ 2012 runtime.

Comment: Can I use msvcp110.dll for the runtime in my project instead of installing it manually on the server?

Comment: You answer is great. For how to automatically install I will open a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Magick.NET Needs VC 2012 Runtime to be installed. (Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012)

Also once Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 is installed on the server, it requires a restart.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate installation of required packages with .ebextensions config file as mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html)