# Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-x86.DLL' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, image-processing, imagemagick, computer-vision

I have used Magick.NET which is a .NET wrapper for ImageMagick, and it throws the above error on a client machine. It works fine on my machine though. I have not installed ImageMagick so I simply can't understand what I need to do on a client machine. I have VS 2012 installed.

Also, Magick.NET includes ImageMagick within it, I think it uses C++/CLI and exposes a .NET interface to the native ImageMagick, all within a single DLL. So what DLL does it need?

(I just came across this error so posting the solution I found.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Magick.NET needs the [VC 2012 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed, and Magick.NET V7+ (.NET 4.0) needs 2012 and the [VC 2015 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) installed. Download and install on client machine. If it pops up a "repair or uninstall" dialog then its already installed and you might be [missing another dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22260912/1294758). If not, install VCR and restart your app.

Comment: +1 Thank you for reading the documentation for me, because apparently I can't do that. The only thing I'll add is that you need the VC 2008 runtime if your Magick.NET app targets .NET 2 or 3.5.

Comment: @JayRiggs - If you are trying to say "RTFM", then all I have to say is, which developer on earth would read the documentation for a LIBRARY to solve an app crash that appears to come from the FRAMEWORK? "Could not load file or assembly.." in no way implies "This library is missing a dependency. Please RTFM to know which." Also, which developer assumes that a light "wrapper" library would require an additional system component that the internal library does not? And lastly, even if you DID read the f'ing manual, you would read the ImageMagick manual, not the 3-page Magick.NET docs.

Comment: @Geotarget both your VC2012 and VC2015 links point to the same place

Comment: The correct link for the VC 2015 runtime is https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: I was getting this even after installing the VC 2015 runtime. I installed 2012 for good measure and now it works.

Comment: @MattBaker - Thanks. Updated post to reflect.

Comment: @HarshGupta Have your issue is resolved, I am also facing same issue. Could you guide me.

Comment: I had to install what you recommended and do this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711520/1325179.  Then I restarted the application pool.

Answer (score 7):

For me one more thing was needed:
in IIS Application pool -> advanced settings -> 
Enable 32-Bit applications

Answer (score 0):

I have error

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'X86' threw an exception. ---> 
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Magick.NET-Q16-x86.Native.dll': Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Fix by set *Application pool -> advanced settings -> Enable 32-Bit =* **false**