# Unable to find an entry point named 'Environment_SetEnv' in DLL 'Magick.NET-Q8-x64.Native.dll'

Tags: magick.net, imagemagick.net

Upgraded to latest ImageMagick / Magick.NET (7.0.2.901), and it built and ran fine locally, but explodes on the server with this error.

> Unable to find an entry point named 'Environment_SetEnv' in DLL 'Magick.NET-Q8-x64.Native.dll'.

Seems to be a new issue. Judging by the change desc here:

https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions/650746

The VC Runtimes are no longer required, so installing them wouldn't be the issue - and, I've installed 2008, 2012 and 2015 VC runtimes for prior versions of the library, which worked fine.

Windows Server 2008 64-bit, 64-bit .Net 4 in IIS.

Current workaround is to roll back to 7.0.0.22, which runs without error.

```
Install-Package Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU -Version 7.0.0.22
```

[image: ImageMagick.X64.Environment_SetEnv(IntPtr name, IntPtr value)]

Comment: Would you mind starting a topic here: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions? I could ask you some questions then.

Comment: You managed to solve this already? I have the same problem on my server. While it works fine locally

Comment: I wanted to gather more diagnostics before posting a bug, and never did it. The fact it has to explode on the server makes gathering those diagnostics a bigger task, since I really need to put it out on a site designed to fail. Will swing back around to it though. But as mentioned workaround is easy, rollback to 7.0.0.22

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue a couple months back and eventually found two separate causes:

1. **AnyCPU Conflict with Previous Versions**

   *Problem*: Magick.NET caches the native library in a temp directory *unless it already exists* ([Relevant source code](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/f329a6deb40b0d1760388355453d36d45a3beeaf/Source/Magick.NET/AnyCPU/NativeLibraryLoader.cs#L116)). Since I had previously tested with the Q8-x64 version (which doesn't test for CPU architecture), the `Magick.NET-Q8-x64.Native.dll` already existed and was not overwritten.

   *Resolution*: Delete the native library's temp directory. On my version of Windows, it was located at `%TEMP%\Magick.NET.{TargetFramework}.{MagickNETVersion}`. The Q8-AnyCPU version then extracted a new native library with the [Environment_SetEnv](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/f329a6deb40b0d1760388355453d36d45a3beeaf/Source/Magick.NET.Native/Helpers/Environment.c#L24) method.
2. **Lack of Permissions in Cache Directory**

   *Problem*: The native library was cached in a directory with restricted permissions for executing code.

   *Resolution*: Change the cache directory's location. My solution is the following code.

   ```cs
    #if DEBUG
    private static bool MagickCacheDirectoryIsSet = false;

    public DefaultConstructor()
    {
        if (!MagickCacheDirectoryIsSet)
        {
            ImageMagick.MagickAnyCPU.CacheDirectory = @"path\to\more\permissive\directory";
            MagickCacheDirectoryIsSet = true;
        }
    }
    #endif
   ```

Comment: I performed #1 (in C:\Windows\Temp), and I did this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23308437/1325179.  Then I restarted the application pool.

Comment: All I had to do was recycle the application pool.  I didn't need to delete any temp files.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to NuGet package manager for the *solution*  (not the project)
2. Uninstall any previous versions of Magick.net
3. Install new version of Magick.net to desired projects
4. Go to the `bin` folder of the main project and delete *any* magick.net file
5. Run your solution

I successfully tested this method on VS2017 and Magick.net 7.6.1 (previous installation was 7.4.4)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, deleting the all magick dlls from the bin folder and reinstall solved it.